# Protected tag error using NDsolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, warning-messages

I have been successful at solving the PDE when I have specified the $r$ I am using, but now when I try and allow $r$ to be a variable and input its value in a function I am getting all sorts of errors and I don't know where to start.

Here are the code and the errors I am getting.

```
T = 1; 
K = 100; 
sigma = 0.1; 
rList = {0.01, 0.05, 0.1}; 
PDE[i_] := D[V[S, t], t] + 
    rList[[i]]*S*D[V[S, t], S] + (sigma^2/2)*S^2*D[V[S, t], {S, 2}] - 
    rList[[i]]*V[S, t] == 0; 
CondCall[i_] := {V[S, T] == Max[S - K, 0], 
   V[1000, t] == 1000 - Exp[(-rList[[i]])*(1 - t)]*K, V[0, t] == 0}; 
SolCall[i_] := 
  NDSolve[{PDE[i], CondCall[i]}, V, {S, 0, 1000}, {t, 0, T}];
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that at some point you gave either `CondCall` or `SolCall` a value. Try restarting the kernel and run the code again.

Comment: @C.E. I used the 'Quit' command and also restarted the programme and got the same errors. Also did "Clear[CondCall,SolCall]' and that didn't help.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful -- It's also good to include the message name (`SetDelayed::write`), which makes it easy to find questions with the same error.

Comment: Like [this search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Set*%20write%20%5berror%5d%20is%3aq)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't see how else I could capture all the error messages I get along with the code

Comment: @DLB You could at least transcribe the code, so people could experiment with it.

Comment: I usally just select all the cells, copy, and paste.  There are essentially only two error message names, `SetDelayed::write` and one having to do with `ReplaceAll`.  If you click on the triple-dot button, you will see message name. -- As a usage practice, I usually put the solver code and the plotting code in separate cells.  I don't execute the plotting code until I know the solver (`NDSolve[]`) worked.

Comment: @ChrisK  I have tried to format the code on the sight now.

Comment: @MichealE2 with your comment, I only find out what NDsolve is when I come to plot the solution since I only define the function.

Comment: Why not include the `Plot[]` code, then?  You can check `SolCall[1]` before plotting.

Comment: Try `Plot[V[S, T/2] /. SolCall[2] // Evaluate, {S, 0, 1000}]`, which works for me.  You need to evaluate `NDSolve` before passing it to `Plot`, but by design, `Plot` "holds" its argument (not allowing to to be evaluated) until `S` has been given a value.  That ruins the functioning of `NDSolve[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a fresh kernel, all you need is an `Evaluate` in the `Plot`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[V[S, 0.5*T] /. SolCall[1]], {S, 70, 130}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't think this will fix the `SetDelayed::write` error....

Comment: I don't get any such errors when starting with a fresh kernel.

Comment: Neither do I...but the OP got them and asked about them.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I guess if OP still gets `SetDelayed::write` errors on a fresh kernel and not running anything else first, then they should post their Mathematica version.

Comment: @ChrisK This worked! Thank you.

Comment: All I meant is that you didn't say anything about a fresh kernel in your ansewr (or mention addressing the source of the error in some other way).  I assume the OP has a lurking def and has not restarted the kernel. (But maybe they did, given their last comment.)  I thought it might need to be explicitly said.  Or one might even give better advice (if the Q was clearer). -- Anyway, I don't want to bug you too much about it.  I thought you'd take my drift in the first comment.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah that slipped by me at first, thanks for the suggestion.  I've added it to my answer.